# Could this RabbitMQ code cause a memory leak

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp

I have the code segment below.  If the RabbitMQ server drops off the connection seems to return null and a new connection is established.  I am suspicious that repeated attempts to reconnect to the server is eating up memory, but I am not sure why.  How should a lost connection (server unavailable) be handled?

```
public Connection getConnection( ) {
    if (myConnection == null) {
        start();
    }
    return myConnection;
}

private void start() {
    log.debug("Building AMQP Connection");

    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    String ipAddress = applicationConfiguration.getAMQPHost();
    String user = applicationConfiguration.getAMQPUser();
    String password = applicationConfiguration.getAMQPPassword();
    String virtualHost = applicationConfiguration.getAMQPVirtualHost();
    String port = applicationConfiguration.getAMQPPort();

    try {
        factory.setUsername(user);
        factory.setPassword(password);
        factory.setVirtualHost(virtualHost);
        factory.setPort(Integer.parseInt(port));
        factory.setHost(ipAddress);
        myConnection = factory.newConnection();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Unable to initialise AMQP Connection.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    myConnection.addBlockedListener(new BlockedListener() {
        public void handleBlocked(String reason) throws IOException {
            // Connection is now blocked
            log.warn("Message Server has blocked.  It may be resource limitted.");
            blocked = true;
        }

        public void handleUnblocked() throws IOException {
            // Connection is now unblocked
            log.warn("Message server is unblocked.");
            blocked = false;
        }
    });
}

public Boolean isBlocked() {
    return blocked;
}
```

The code is part of a messaging system that redirects in bound messages to an outgoing AMQP queue.  Each time an in bound message is received (at a rate of 20 to 30 per second) the getConnection method is called.  If the AMQP server is down, the method is still called and an attempt is made to build a queue.  It fails throwing an exception seemingly eating more memory with each failure.

Comment: Why do you think there is a memory leak?  Do you have OutOfMemory errors?

Comment: Apologies, yes.  I noticed when the application is trying to connect repeatedly it throws an OutOfMemory exception

Comment: in what part of the code connection becomes NULL ? what does retrigger start method?

Comment: I'm not sure this question is answerable- it seems like there is more information needed (e.g. higher-level view of your program, not just the connection method).

Comment: Thank you for the comments.  I will try to update the question.